# Display errors generated in PHP file back to HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form that calls a php file to submit a form. I can get errors to generate when validation fails however the errors need to be displayed on a newly created html page within the php file.

Is there a way to pass errors back to the original form to display the error on the form ?

Snippets from PHP file is shown below:

```
/* If name is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $first_name))
{
    show_error("Name not valid");
}
```

....

```
function show_error($myError)
{
?>

    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You would do it with AJAX if you do not want to reload the page.

Comment: billions of names will fail that test.

Comment: @Dagon, why ? any suggestions to prevent these 'billions' of names failing ?

Comment: billions of people dont use the English\Latin alphabet. heard of China?

Comment: Even in English, a name such as D'vonte would fail that test.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   $errors = array();
   ... validate form stuff ...
   .... $errors[] = "You didn't fill out something ...";

   if(count($errors) == 0) {
       ... success ... 
       do stuff with data
       exit();
   }

}

.... display form...
if (count($errors) > 0) {
   display errors
}
```

Comment: So you saying i need to recall the form within the PHP file ?
So still generate the new html page but add the form code again ?